# creating two child processes in C and execute them one after the other

Tags: c, linux, fork, child-process

I have two programs say program_A and program_B, they will be called from my C code. program_B has to be only executed after program_A finishes its work.

I tried to use fork() and execl() to accomplish my goal, but seems like program_B wont be executed at all.. can any one give me the correct structure on in what order should I create my child processes?

Comment: Probably `waitpid()`. Or just use `system()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `wait` for the first child to finish, then `fork` and `execl` the next child.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void die(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        die("fork A");

    if (pid == 0) { // child
        execl("./program_A", "program_A", (char*)0);
        die("exec A");
    } else {        // parent
        wait(NULL);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            die("fork B");
        if (pid == 0) { // child
            execl("./program_B", "program_B", (char*)0);
            die("exec B");
        } else {        // parent
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Done.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```